# Numerical approximation for leaky tanks

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I am going through the material from MIT OCW and I have one small problem with one of the tasks.
[Screenshot of the task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT8TL.png)

In the part I'm having problem with, I'm supposed to use forward Euler approximation to calculate `r1(t)` and `r2(t)`.

I get the following equation for r1:

```
r1[n] = T/20 * (r0[n-1] - r1[n-1]) + r1[n-1]
```

And, then `r0` is held constant at 0.1:

```
r1[n] = T/20 * (0.1 - r1[n-1]) + r1[n-1]
```

So, I would expect it to be similar for `r2`:

```
r2[n] = T/10 * (r1[n-1] - r2[n-1]) + r2[n-1]
```

However, in the solutions for this assignment, the enclosed code is the following:

```
for i in range(1,60):
    r1.append(r1[i-1]+T/20.*(0.1-r1[i-1]))
    r2.append(r2[i-1]+T/10.*(r1[i]-r2[i-1]))
```

While I would expect the following line:

```
    r2.append(r2[i-1]+T/10.*(r1[i-1]-r2[i-1]))
```

So, why it should be `r1[i]` and not `r1[i-1]`? Thanks for any help.

[PDF with full task & solution - Task 6.(f)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-003-signals-and-systems-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_003F11_sol01.pdf)